# Insert data into the database

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am not able to enter data in the magento tables, what am I doing wrong?
In var_dump it returns me the data correctly, it just does not re-insert into the table I want

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
    require_once('app/Mage.php');
    Mage::app(0);

    $users = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();

    $i = 1;
    foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
    $id = $user->getId();

    $usuario_loaded = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);

                $tudo = array(
                'clientes_id'=>$usuario_loaded->getId(),  
                'nome'=>$usuario_loaded->getFirstname(),
                'sobrenome'=>$usuario_loaded->getLastname(),
                'loja'=>$usuario_loaded->getWebsiteId(),
                'grupo'=>$usuario_loaded->getGroupId(),
                'prefixo'=>$usuario_loaded->getPrefix(),
                'assinatura'=>$usuario_loaded->getMiddlename(),
                'cpf'=>$usuario_loaded->getCpf(),
                'cnpj'=>$usuario_loaded->getCnpj(),
                'razao'=>$usuario_loaded->getCompanyName(),
                'fantasia'=>$usuario_loaded->getTradingName(),
                'apelido'=>$usuario_loaded->getNickname(),
                'insestadual'=>$usuario_loaded->getIe(),
                'tipocadastro'=>$usuario_loaded->getType(),
                'profissao'=>$usuario_loaded->getOccupation(),
                'fundação'=>$usuario_loaded->getFoundationDay(),
                'sufixo'=>$usuario_loaded->getSuffix(),
                'email'=>$usuario_loaded->getEmail(),
                'emailsec'=>$usuario_loaded->getEmailSeconday(),
                'emailfiscal'=>$usuario_loaded->getEmailBilling(),
                'nascimento'=>$usuario_loaded->getDob(),
                'cpfcnpj'=>$usuario_loaded->getTaxvat(),
                'sexo'=>$usuario_loaded->getGender(),
                'departamento'=>$usuario_loaded->getDepartment(),
                'ondeconheceu'=>$usuario_loaded->getHowFindUs(),
                'adyen'=>$usuario_loaded->getAdyenCustomerRef());


                var_dump($tudo);

                $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
                $query = "INSERT INTO clientes (clientes_id, nome, sobrenome, loja, grupo, prefixo, assinatura, cpf, cnpj, razao, fantasia, apelido, insestadual, tipocadastro, profissao, fundação, sufixo, email, emailsec, emailfiscal, nascimento, cpfcnpj, sexo, departamento, ondeconheceu, adyen) VALUES ('".$tudox['clientes_id']."', '".$tudox['nome']."', '".$tudox['sobrenome']."', '".$tudox['loja']."', '".$tudox['grupo']."', '".$tudox['prefixo']."', '".$tudox['assinatura']."', '".$tudox['cpf']."', '".$tudox['cnpj']."', '".$tudox['razao']."', '".$tudox['fantasia']."', '".$tudox['apelido']."', '".$tudox['insestadual']."', '".$tudox['tipocadastro']."', '".$tudox['profissao']."', '".$tudox['fundação']."', '".$tudox['sufixo']."', '".$tudox['email']."', '".$tudox['emailsec']."', '".$tudox['emailfiscal']."', '".$tudox['nascimento']."', '".$tudox['cpfcnpj']."', '".$tudox['sexo']."', '".$tudox['departamento']."', '".$tudox['ondeconheceu']."', '".$tudox['adyen']."')";
                $connection->query($query);

    $i++;
    if ($i == 1) {
    break;
    }



}
?>
```

Comment: What are you doing.
If possible create a custom module with minimum required files.
Or use Magento way to save you data.

Comment: `Its not a good idea and not safe. When you use the normal magento method of changing the data, a number of events are fired off and sometimes those events are used to make additional modifications or updates within the site.`

Comment: you can follow https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/

Comment: I have to run this script "out" of the magento, I just gave a get in the mage to be able to use the functions, I would just like to remove those records and insert them into another table, I can make up the magento with php, I can not, I've tried both ways.